# Design decision for object representation and conversion

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I need to map between different entities in order to create synch tool between two systems. The mapping is 1:1, and I have about 4-5 different entities that I will map between.

E.g

```
A1 -> B1
A2 -> B2
A3 -> B3
```

Communication is in JSON through REST API, and I will have to transform/convert an object into its JSON representation for different requests.

I wish to know about your ideas between the following decisions:

1) In each class, create a class method that knows how to convert to its corresponding object in the other system. Each class knows how to represent itself by implementing methods toJSON, toXML.

E.g

```
class A1 {
    static A2 toA2(A1 a1) return { }
    String toJSON() return { }
} 
class A2 {
    static A1 toA1(A2 a2) return { }
    String to JSON() return { }
}
```

2) Straight away use a converter class (Object -> JSON) with methods for converting an object to the corresponding JSON in the other system. E.g. 
`Converter.entityAtoEntityBJSON(aEntityA)` returns a JSON representation of entity A in entity B's system.

The second option will result in the converter class knowing about every entity, while in 1) only two classes know about each other. Also, should it be required to represent XML, each class can then implement a toXML().

What do you think?

Edit: added note about REST API.

Comment: There are many other options and, your example code is syntactically incorrect, styling issues aside. If you want to pass data between "systems" then you will have to serliaize to some format. Why not use Protobuf.net http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net? If `A1` and `A2` are parts of different "systems" how could the direct conversion code work?

Comment: I only wished to illustrate two choices, syntax is irrelevant actually and sorry if that wasn't clear enough. I am not sure serialization is the best choice here, merely because it is very small amount of data that needs to be communicated through REST.

Comment: that is the crux of it. What data do you actually want to pass between the systems? If both systems are using a REST interface then that data need only be transmitable via an HTTP request.

Comment: Data is simple text strings in JSON format. Id, key, entityType, date-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well although the first option seem compelling but i find that it breaks the [SRP](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) (Single Responsibility Principle) because it now has more than a single reason to change, each entity knows how to convert it self to other forms so whenever you change the representation format or structure you will have to modify each entity. So i prefer the second option to centralize change. i would use an interface like `IMapper` that takes an entity and converts it to an entity in the other system. This is similiar to the way most ORMs work to store you objects into databases.

Comment: You mean like this:  interface IMapper { A1 mapToA1(A2 a2); A2 mapToA2(A1 a1); } ?

Comment: @hajder, yes i might do something similar, and don't worry the interface is going to know about (depend) on all those entities, this way you can centralize change in one location.